# Restructure column to row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a lot of data from a laboratories, however, they structure the data in a way that makes further work really annoying and time consuming.

[image: Snip of data]

In `M`, I have the parameter and in `N`, I have the value to that parameter, `B` is the key to each parameter. What I'm trying to do is make a table with the parameter as a header and the value for each sample below the parameter.

In this datasheet there are more then 7000 rows so doing it by hand is far to time consuming. I have tried using a INDEX - MATCH function to match B with the parameter and value but i can't seem to figure it out.

I have left a picture of what im trying to end up with but with some other parameters.

[image: Wish goal]

This is a version from another lab and basically this is that im trying to archive. I hope someone can help me towards that goal.

Comment: You could transpose the data if you need it in column instead of row ( https://support.office.com/de-de/article/Transponieren-Vertauschen-von-Daten-aus-Spalten-in-Zeilen-oder-umgekehrt-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744 ) and use row/column grouping to collapse a single parameter ( https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08CE98C4-0063-4D42-8AC7-8278C49E9AFF )

Comment: Maybe a pivot table?

Comment: Microsoft's [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6E92E2F4-2079-4E1F-BAD5-89F6269CD605) is an Excel add-in that allows you to create and repeat a series of [data transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation).  For smaller workbooks there are simpler methods but with larger datasets it really comes into it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want the following:

**Column M** as the header. 
**Column B** as the rows. 
**Column N** as the corresponding value of the header and the rows.

**Step 1)** Mark the values in **Column M**, then **copy**, and **paste** it with the **TRANSPOSE** option. See more details [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744).

**Step 2)** Copy the values in **Column B** into **Column A** to get the row description.

After those two steps your table should look like this:

```
            A              B             C              D
1                       Benzen      EthyBenzen       m*p-Xxen
2    835-2017-5623
3    835-2017-5624
4    835-2017-5625
```

**Step 3)** Insert the following formula **only** in **Cell B2** 
*Maybe you need to modify the row numbers in case your data base is > 10.000*

```
=ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,IF($M$1:$M$10000=B$1,$B$1:$N$10000,""),13,FALSE),"")
```

**Step 4)** Mark the **entire formula** from Step 3) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> so the formula will be in **{}**.

**Step 5)** Drag the formula down and to the right to fill out all your table.

After those three steps your table should look like this:

```
            A              B             C              D
1                       Benzen      EthyBenzen       m*p-Xxen
2    835-2017-5623      >0,1
3    835-2017-5624                    >0,1
4    835-2017-5625                                      >0,1
```

Comment: It seems to work great as a start, however I can't seem to get the values to run in the next rows. So i was thinking, is there a way to use B as a "key" to match the correct M and N to the VLOOKUP?

Comment: Check my edits (Step 2 - 5) and let me know if it gives you the desired result.

Comment: I get "Too many arguments in the formular if i copy paste it and use CTRL+SHIFT+Enter. If i remove the last two "" i get a return but it's TRUE

Comment: mmmh, I tried the example again and for met it worked without any issue. From my expereicne the"Too many arguments" error usually happens when you accidentally delete a parenthesis or a comma by modifying the formula. Try again and check carefully if the strucutre of the formula remains the same after you modified it. Besides, do not forget that you first have to enter the formula ONLY in cell B2 and press the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER command and then drag it down and to the right.